# How to print numbers n...0 with python?

Tags: python

I'm very new to coding, and I have now faced a problem. I'd like to print every number between N and 0, where N is an input of any integer. The code below has something wrong with it, but what should I do? Sorry for such a novice question, I couldn't find any solutions. :(

```
print("Insert integer:")
x = int(input())
while x>0: 
  print(x) 
  x=x-1
while x <0: 
  print(x) 
  x=x+1
```

Comment: What, precisely, is wrong with this code? What's it doing differently from what you want it to do?

Comment: The first loop will print the numbers `N` to `0`. Why do you need the second loop?

Comment: @Aziz in case x is negative

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy the loops are not printing numbers N...0 but N...1 or N...-1

Comment: Change `x>0` to `x>=0` so it includes `0`.

Comment: Your description is confusing, reading your code seems like the `N` could be positive or negative, and print decreasingly or increasingly until hitting `0`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing `0` because the condition `x > 0` is not true when `x == 0`, and neither is `x < 0`.

Change the second loop to include `0` with `x <= 0`.

```
x = int(input("Enter integer:"))
while x > 0: 
    print(x) 
    x = x-1
while x <= 0: 
    print(x) 
    x = x+1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a more neat way of doing this you can use

```
N = int(input("Insert integer: "))
print(*range(N,-1,-1))
```

here N is the starting number, -1 is the end, though it is not inclusive so 0 will be the last number printed and the last -1 is the increment or in this case decrement

Comment: To kinda mimic the by line printing add `sep='\n'` to the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

This will print every integer from N to zero (going down from positive and up from negative).

```
print("Insert integer:")
x = int(input())
if x >= 0:
   for value in reversed(range(x+1)):
      print(value)
else:
   for value in range(x,1):
      print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print negative integers from N to -1

```
start_num = int(input("Please enter your negativ number:? "))
end_num = int(input("Enter the end of range:? "))
for i in range(start_num, end_num, 1):
    if i < 0:
        print(i, end=" ")
```

The result will be

```
Please enter your negativ number:? -15
Enter the end of range:? 0
-15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Print out positiv integer from 1 to the second to last thing in a series and print out negative integers from N to -1

```
num = int(input("Enter your integer number:? "))

for i in range(num):
    if i > 0:
        
        print(i, end=" ")
        i = i + 1 

   
while num < 0:
    print(num, end=" ")
    num = num + 1
  
Enter your integer number:? 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
>>> 

Enter your integer number:? -10
-10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).